# How do i perform delete operation of a specific child in Firebase using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to code the delete function for my table which is using Firebase Realtime db. I'm kinda new to this but i need help.

I'm trying to fetch the child id and pass it to a function to delete it, So far..

```
    var mainApp = {};
    (function(){

    var firebase = app_firebase;
    var uid = null;


    function fnHRead() {
    var path = 'institutions/' + uid;
    app_firebase.databaseApi.read(path, sucessFn, messageHandler)
    function sucessFn(snapShot){
        if(!!snapShot && !!snapShot.val()){
        //console.log(snapShot.val());
        var inst_info = snapShot.val();
        var keys = Object.keys(inst_info);
        console.log(keys);
        var html = "<table class='centered' border='1|1'>";
        html+= "<thead>";
        html+= "<tr>";
        html+= "<th>Institution Name</th>";
        html+= "<th>Proprietor</th>";
        html+= "<th>Phone</th>";
        html+= "<th>Email</th>";
        html+= "<th>Locality</th>";
        html+= "<th>City</th>";
        html+= "<th>Manage</th>";
        html+= "</tr>";
        html+= "</thead>";

        for (var i = 0;i < keys.length; i++){
            var k = keys[i];
            var name = inst_info[k].inst_name;
            var ownerName = inst_info[k].inst_owner;
            var email = inst_info[k].inst_email;
            var phone = inst_info[k].inst_phone;
            var locality = inst_info[k].inst_locality;
            var city = inst_info[k].inst_city;
            var path = keys[i];

            html+="<tr>";
            html+="<td>"+name+"</td>";
            html+="<td>"+ownerName+"</td>";
            html+="<td>"+phone+"</td>";
            html+="<td>"+email+"</td>";
            html+="<td>"+locality+"</td>";
            html+="<td>"+city+"</td>";
            html+="<td><a class='waves-effect waves-light btn red' onclick='mainApp.deletePatient("+path+")'>Delete</a></td>";
            html+="</tr>";
            //console.log(name,ownerName,email,phone,locality,city);
            console.log(path);

        }
        html+="</table>";
            document.getElementById("manageExist").innerHTML = html;
            M.toast({html: 'Institution list Fetch Sucessfull', classes: 'rounded'});

        }else{
        console.log("No data");
        M.toast({html: 'Institution list Fetch Unsucessful', classes: 'rounded'});
        }
    }   
    }

    function fnHDelete(path){
        app_firebase.databaseApi.delete(path, messageHandler);

    }
    mainApp.deletePatient = fnHDelete;
    })()
```

Another .js which contains the firebase credentials and functions for CRUD operation

```
    function dbDelete(path, callBack){
        if(!path) return;
        app_firebase.database().ref(path).remove(callBack);

    }
```

Error i get in the console:

```
    dashboard.html:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: LXntMDT74LL_suY6Ar0 is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (dashboard.html:1)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, javascript is a language specifically for the client side and a user application should, under no circumstances, ever talk directly to the database due to several security problems.

To answer your question: Firebase has a `removeValue()` command you can use to delete an element: [Docs Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#updating_or_deleting_data)

Edit: You are calling the callback to be removed, not the path. Not quite sure, if that's the error, but it's worth a shot.